# iOS tableview customcell - controls on offscreen cell are sometimes not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I got a weird bug on a table view with 5 cells. The fifth cell is initially off screen due to large cell heights and the user needs to scroll down to see it. The cells are displaying a download button, a progress indicator and if the download is complete, a View button instead of the download and progress.

The first 4 cells display properly. The fifth cell however is sometimes missing the download button but sometimes it is displayed correctly at about a %50 chance on each app restart. The source data is not changed at any point.

I've used breakpoints to see what happens when I scroll down, but I could not spot anything unusual and the data was served correctly when the cell appeared.

Can anybody tell where I should be focusing?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell1";
    NSDictionary *categoryDictionary= [[appdelegate categoriesArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    categoryTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];    
    rect=cell.labelProgressView.frame;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor PGColorBackground];    
    cell.buttonView.hidden=YES;        
    //Set background colors and icons
    switch ([[categoryDictionary valueForKey:@"categoryID"] intValue])
    {
        case 1:
            [cell.buttonView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor PGColorAttractions]] ;
            [cell.labelProgressView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor PGColorAttractions]] ;
            [cell.ivCategoryBannerImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"attraction-bg"]];
            cell.ivcategoryLogoImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"attractionWhite"];
            break;
        case 2:
            [cell.buttonView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor PGColorRestaurants]];
            [cell.labelProgressView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor PGColorRestaurants]];
            [cell.ivCategoryBannerImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"restaurant-bg"]];
            cell.ivcategoryLogoImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"restaurantWhite"];
            break;
        case 3:
            [cell.buttonView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor  PGColorShopping]];
            [cell.labelProgressView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor PGColorShopping]];
            [cell.ivCategoryBannerImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"shopping-bg"]];
            cell.ivcategoryLogoImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"shoppingWhite"];
            break;
        case 4:
            [cell.buttonView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor  PGColorAccomodations]];
            [cell.labelProgressView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor PGColorAccomodations]];
            [cell.ivCategoryBannerImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"accomodation-bg"]];
            cell.ivcategoryLogoImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"accomodationWhite"];
            break;

        case 5:
            [cell.buttonView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor PGColorArtGalleries]];
            [cell.labelProgressView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor PGColorArtGalleries]];
            [cell.ivCategoryBannerImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"artGallery-bg"]];
            cell.ivcategoryLogoImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"artGalleryWhite"];
            break;

        default:
            break;            
    }

    //DOWNLOAD Button
    [cell.buttonViewDownload setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    cell.buttonViewDownload.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    cell.buttonViewDownload.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    [cell.buttonViewDownload.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:10]];
    [cell.buttonViewDownload setTag:[[categoryDictionary valueForKey:@"categoryID"] intValue]];

    //VIEW Button
    cell.buttonView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    cell.buttonView.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    [cell.buttonView.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:10]];
    [cell.buttonView setTag:[[categoryDictionary valueForKey:@"categoryID"] intValue]];
    [cell.buttonView addTarget:self action:@selector(viewbuttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //CATEGORY label

    NSString *categoryName =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[categoryDictionary valueForKey:@"categoryNameen"]] uppercaseString];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
    attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:categoryName];

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                            value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8.0]
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [categoryName length])];

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                            value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:19]
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [categoryName length])];


    [cell.labelCategory setAttributedText:attributedString];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;    
    //Set State    
    cell.ivCategoryBannerImage.alpha =0.1f;

    BOOL isAvailable = [[categoryDictionary valueForKey:@"isAvailable"] boolValue];
    BOOL userTappedDownload = [[categoryDictionary valueForKey:@"userTappedDownload"] boolValue];

    NSLog(@"isAvailable: %d", isAvailable);
    NSLog(@"userTappedDownload: %d", isAvailable);

    if (isAvailable && userTappedDownload)
    {
        cell.buttonView.hidden=NO;
        [cell.buttonView setTitle:@"VIEW" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.buttonViewDownload.hidden=YES;
        cell.ivCategoryBannerImage.alpha =1.0f;
        rect.size.width=208.0f;
    }
    else if(!isAvailable && !userTappedDownload)
    {
        rect.size.width=0.1f;
        [cell.buttonViewDownload setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DOWNLOAD (%@ KB)",[categoryDictionary valueForKey:@"totalImagesSize"]] forState:0];            
    }
    else if(!isAvailable && userTappedDownload)
    {
        rect.size.width=[[categoryDictionary valueForKey:@"totalImagesAvailable"] intValue];
        [cell.buttonViewDownload setTitle:@"DOWNLOADING CONTENT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.buttonViewDownload.userInteractionEnabled = NO;      
    }    
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the fifth cell is reusing one of the previous cell's that set `cell.buttonViewDownload.hidden=YES;`.

Try adding `cell.buttonViewDownload.hidden=NO;` to the branch that should show the download button.

Comment: Yes, works, thank you for restoring my hope in obj-C : )